# Find coordinates of tap event when using iScroll

Tags: cordova, coordinates, iscroll

I was using [iscroll-zoom.js](http://iscrolljs.com/) in a Phonegap app to display a large image, and I wanted to detect the x,y coordinates of any point the user touched. I was having trouble testing on Android as the event object had pageX and pageY = zero, regardless of where I tapped.

After much grief I think I am able to answer that question, as I eventually discovered the iScroll object had its own pointX and pointY properties which gave me what I wanted. But: **Where are these properties documented online?!** Seriously, Google returns nothing useful for "iscroll pointX" let alone "iscroll tap coordinates".

I will post my code below, but would welcome your comments or alternatives, and would love to see a link to all the other iScroll documentation I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code which gave me the coordinates of where I touched the image, regardless of where it was scrolled to, or zoomed:

```
document.addEventListener('tap', tap_on_floor_plan, false);
setTimeout(function () {
    myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {
        zoom: true,
        scrollX: true,
        scrollY: true,
        tap: true,
        mouseWheel: true,
        wheelAction: 'zoom'
    });
}, 100);

function tap_on_floor_plan(ev) {
    var iTapX = Math.round(((myScroll.x * -1) + myScroll.pointX) / myScroll.scale, 0);
    var iTapY = Math.round(((myScroll.y * -1) + myScroll.pointY - iHeaderTopGap) / myScroll.scale, 0);

}
```

myScroll.pointX is where you tapped, relative to edge of visible screen.

myScroll.x is the how far you've scrolled/zoomed: zero when you start, then becomes more negative as you zoom/move

I had to subtract the height of a header that was showing above the scrollable image (calculated elsewhere).